# How to optimize LINQ DB request?

Tags: c#, linq

I have next code, taking Last and Pre-Last params of elemensts in DB:

```
var result =  _context.Contacts.Where(conts => conts.CreatorUserId == _userManager.GetUserId(this.User))
     .Select(conts => new
     {
         conts.ID,
         conts.Mobile,
         conts.Email,
         conts.Facebook,
         conts.StateId,
         conts.CreatorUserId,
         conts.Birthday,
         conts.Description,
         conts.Name,
         conts.Photo,
         conts.SecondName,

         Tags = conts.Tags.Select(d=> d.UserTag.Emoji),
         NpaId = conts.NpaInfo.NpaId,

         PartnerPvPrev = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.MyPV).FirstOrDefault(),
         GroupPvPrev = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.GroupPV).FirstOrDefault(),
         LevelPrev = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.PerformanceBonusLevelId).FirstOrDefault(),


         PartnerPv = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Take(1).Select(x => x.MyPV).FirstOrDefault(),
         Level = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Take(1).Select(x => x.PerformanceBonusLevelId).FirstOrDefault(),// conts.NpaInfo.PerformanceBonusLevelId,
         GroupPv = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Take(1).Select(x => x.GroupPV).FirstOrDefault(),

         EntryDate = conts.NpaInfo.EntryDate,
         ExpirationDate = conts.NpaInfo.ExpirationDate
     });
```

In fact the part :

```
PartnerPvPrev = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.MyPV).FirstOrDefault(),
GroupPvPrev = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.GroupPV).FirstOrDefault(),
LevelPrev = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.PerformanceBonusLevelId).FirstOrDefault()
```

converts to something like this in 1 request (show you only part for one block):

```
 SELECT TOP(1) [t0].[MyPV]
    FROM (
        SELECT [x0].[MyPV], [x0].[DataMonth]
        FROM [NpaDatas] AS [x0]
        WHERE [conts.NpaInfo].[ID] = [x0].[NpaInfoId]
        ORDER BY [x0].[DataMonth] DESC
        OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS [t0]
    ORDER BY [t0].[DataMonth] DESC
) AS [PartnerPvPrev], (
    SELECT TOP(1) [t1].[GroupPV]
    FROM (
        SELECT [x1].[GroupPV], [x1].[DataMonth]
        FROM [NpaDatas] AS [x1]
        WHERE [conts.NpaInfo].[ID] = [x1].[NpaInfoId]
        ORDER BY [x1].[DataMonth] DESC
        OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS [t1]
    ORDER BY [t1].[DataMonth] DESC
) AS [GroupPvPrev], (
    SELECT TOP(1) [t2].[PerformanceBonusLevelId]
    FROM (
        SELECT [x2].[PerformanceBonusLevelId], [x2].[DataMonth]
        FROM [NpaDatas] AS [x2]
        WHERE [conts.NpaInfo].[ID] = [x2].[NpaInfoId]
        ORDER BY [x2].[DataMonth] DESC
        OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
    ) AS [t2]
    ORDER BY [t2].[DataMonth] DESC
) AS [LevelPrev]
```

I dont want to repeat the same part multiple times:

```
conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1)
```

So, if I do like this :

```
PrevBuffer = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Skip(1).Take(1).Select(                               
     param => new
     {

         param.MyPV,
         param.GroupPV,
         param.PerformanceBonusLevelId
     }
     ),
```

It will display many separate requests in output for each row like:

```
SELECT [x0].[MyPV], [x0].[GroupPV], [x0].[PerformanceBonusLevelId]
FROM [NpaDatas] AS [x0]
WHERE @_outer_ID1 = [x0].[NpaInfoId]
ORDER BY [x0].[DataMonth] DESC
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

The same is about this part :

```
Tags = conts.Tags.Select(d=> d.UserTag.Emoji)
```

Will get multiple selects like:

```
SELECT [d.UserTag].[Emoji]
FROM [ContactTags] AS [d]
LEFT JOIN [UserTags] AS [d.UserTag] ON [d].[UserTagId] = [d.UserTag].[ID]
WHERE @_outer_ID = [d].[ContactId]
```

Can it be optimized somehow?

Comment: Instead of two queries... `Skip(1).Take(1)` and then later `Take(1)` you could try combining to a single query of `Take(2)` and then perform the logic client side (there may exist a `Take(2)` solution that's all Db side, I don't know)... That would cut your total queries in half at the very least

Comment: You really should show a [mcve]. You've pasted code that appears to be part of a `new` anonymous object creation. All of the hard DB works happens outside of this and that would be what we need to see to optimise the query.

Comment: Updated the code for full version.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like this will improve the query significantly.

```
var result = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth).Take(2).ToArray();

PartnerPvPrev = result.Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.MyPV).FirstOrDefault();
  GroupPvPrev = result.Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.GroupPV).FirstOrDefault();
    LevelPrev = result.Skip(1).Take(1).Select(x => x.PerformanceBonusLevelId).FirstOrDefault();
    PartnerPv = result.Take(1).Select(x => x.MyPV).FirstOrDefault();
        Level = result.Take(1).Select(x => x.PerformanceBonusLevelId).FirstOrDefault();
      GroupPv = result.Take(1).Select(x => x.GroupPV).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: But ToArray() will fetch all fields of NpaData, I need only 6 of them (3 of Last and 3 of Prev). Why do I need select here again, in your case, if I can just Index value like : result[0].MyPv

Comment: @user2377299 - Then select the three fields before the `.ToArray()`. And I kept the original code for simplicity.

Comment: @Enigmativity Can you explain a bit how it's better than the solution in question itself?

Comment: The `.ToArray()` forces the query execution so that there is only one query sent to the DB. The 6 following lines all then work from the data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should select the repetitive parts first and use these in the subsequent query. This is much easier in query syntax, using the `let` keyword:

```
var result = from conts in _context.Contacts
    where conts.CreatorUserId == _userManager.GetUserId(this.User)
    let monthsSorted = conts.NpaInfo.NpaData.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth)
    let firstMonth = monthsSorted.FirstOrDefault()
    let prevMonth = monthsSorted.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        conts.ID,
        conts.Mobile,
        conts.Email,
        conts.Facebook,
        conts.StateId,
        conts.CreatorUserId,
        conts.Birthday,
        conts.Description,
        conts.Name,
        conts.Photo,
        conts.SecondName,

        Tags = conts.Tags.Select(d=> d.UserTag.Emoji),
        NpaId = conts.NpaInfo.NpaId,

        PartnerPvPrev = prevMonth.MyPV,
        GroupPvPrev = prevMonth.GroupPV,
        LevelPrev = prevMonth.PerformanceBonusLevelId,

        PartnerPv = firstMonth.MyPV,
        GroupPv = firstMonth.GroupPV,
        Level = firstMonth.PerformanceBonusLevelId,

        EntryDate = conts.NpaInfo.EntryDate,
        ExpirationDate = conts.NpaInfo.ExpirationDate
    };
```

Comment: It does multiple selects too for each of that 6 values. Like :
 SELECT [x].[MyPV]
    FROM [NpaDatas] AS [x]
    WHERE [conts.NpaInfo].[ID] = [x].[NpaInfoId]
    ORDER BY [x].[DataMonth] DESC
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

Comment: OK, apparently this is LINQ-to-SQL (please always use specific tags). In Entity Framework this would make a significant difference. I'm afraid your only option is not to collect all data in one query because LINQ-to-SQL will always do this inefficiently.

Comment: I've looked into this once more and really, this your only option --or your original query, but then at least my query is easier to read. With LINQ-to-SQL you'll always get a subquery per `conts.NpaInfo.NpaData` property you want to have in the result. I've looked into alternatives with getting collections of 2 `conts.NpaInfo.NpaData` items (`Take(2)`) and flatten the result later, but this always produces N+1 queries. If the current query performs reasonably, go for it, otherwise find another way to collect the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a GroupBy :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Conts conts = new Conts();

            List<NpaDatas> data = conts.NpaInfo.NpaDatas
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.DataMonth)
                .GroupBy(x => x.DataMonth).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

            //To get the second latest use followng
            NPaDatas results = data.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public class NpaDatas
    {
        public string NpaInfoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataMonth { get; set; }
        public PV PartnerPv { get; set; }
        public PV PerformanceBonusLevelId { get; set; }
        public PV GroupPv { get; set; }
    }
    public class PV
    {
        //data not specified 
    }
    public class Conts
    {
        public NpaInfo NpaInfo { get; set; }
    }
    public class NpaInfo
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public List<NpaDatas> NpaDatas { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe there is some misunderstand. NpaInfo has multiple NpaData. And each NpaData has Level,PartnerPv,GrouPv. I need to fetch the Last and pre-Last items. NpaData does not contains both 6 fields.

Comment: I updated my code based on the SQL you posted but you SQL doesn't look right.  I don't understand why you need to filter for ID.  I suspect you should have a List<NpaInfo> and each should only have the same ID.  Also the SQL posted has extra closing parenthesis which means you didn't post the entire SQL.

Comment: Contact has one NpaInfo. NpaInfo has many NpaData with different dates. I need 3 parms from each (Last and PreLast) NpaData of NpaInfo of Contacts created by current user. SQL - shorted only with problem part that duplicates.

Comment: So you argre with me that the ID of NpaInfo and the NapDatta will be the same so you do not need to filter for ID?  Is there anything wrong with my Query?

Comment: NpaInfo.ID != NapData.ID -  two different objects. Where do I filter by ID ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to.  Your SQL has : WHERE [conts.NpaInfo].[ID] = [x0].[NpaInfoId],  I attempted to model you database using classes based on the SQL you provided.  I think something is not consistent that is why I'm asking the questions.  I suspect that NpaInfo is an array but not sure.You didn't post the entire SQL and said it was to shorten to only post the problem part.  I can't help simplify the query without knowing the real structure.  Not attempting to reverse engineer your posted sql.

Comment: NpaInfo contains : virtual ICollection<NpaData> NpaData { get; set; }
NpaData  contains : public int? NpaInfoId { get; set; }  public virtual NpaInfo NpaInfo { get; set; }
That WHERE is generated by EF =(

Comment: Isn't the ID being duplicated unnecessarily?

Comment: It's classic Razor Pages pattern to link object to cascade deletion from DB.

Comment: See webpage : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio.  If you look at Model at top of page at students ID. The ID is in Student and Enrollment.  You do not need both because they are one-to-one.  The Course table has a list of students taking each course and is linked in the class model.  You only need the ID in both Student and Enrollment tables if you need to do a join in SQL (not in the class model).  I think the razor code will automatically do the join so the where isn't needed. You do not need both JOIN and WHERE.